# ionic 6 capacitor QR code scanner inside a page content

Tags: ionic-framework, qr-code, capacitor

I'm using Ionic 6 with capacitor, is there a way to show the camera preview inside a specific div? Actually with any QR code plugin, is only possible to scan a QR code with a new camera preview window.

Thanks